# Is it possible to rerun interrupted SVN checkout from the place of interruption?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am doing long checkout with eclipse's Subclipse and getting interrupt in the middle. When I try to run checkout again, Eclipse says that folder already exists and will be deleted. After that checkout runs from the very beginning, downloading files again.

Isn't Subversion intended to update gradually?

Whose this bug is, Subclipse's or Subversion's? Will one be able to rerun interrupted checkout from the place of interruption with any other SVN clients?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following answers

[svn resuming aborted checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout)

[Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err)

I can deduce, that after checkout abort, project should be "created" with the same name, which will connect it to eclipse, then SVN menu will become available, from within where update or other operations can be done