# Subversive SVN Checkout only missing files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive, svn-checkout

I am using eclipse plugin '`subversive SVN`' as my SVN tool.

My remote repository is huge (of more than `30GB`) , and when I tried to download I lost the connection in between (say `94%` ) .

I need to checkout only the remaining , missing files.

If I click checkout option, it will delete all the existing files and will start from the scratch again which I don't want .

Is there any better solution , to download only the missing files from `SVN` repo ?

[image]

**UPDATE :**

I opened command window (cmd ) in that location . And typed these commands.

```
svn cleanup

svn update
```

Fixed my issue  .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svn resuming aborted checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout), you can consult the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html).

> If you interrupt a checkout (or something else interrupts your checkout, such as loss of connectivity, etc.), you can restart it either by issuing the identical checkout command again or by updating the incomplete working copy:

Comment: Can you guide me how ?

Comment: @Seb please provide links to an up-to-date documentation. SVNBook 1.5 is very outdated. Therefore, I updated the link to point to SVNBook 1.8.

Comment: @SujithPS are you sure that the eclipse implementation will delete everything you've already checked out and redownload everything, rather than following the normal SVN behaviour?

Comment: @Seb :  Yes. That happened 3 times. I lost 40 GB of data already (to download 30 GB data in total ) .I checked the folder after clicking on 'checkout' , it deleted all the data in the folder.